# How to prevent unhandled panic from crashing my application process

Tags: go, panic

I want a mechanism by which any unhandled panic (from Go code) does not bring down my application process. At the moment any downstream panic(s) raised by my golang code will freeze/crash my application. How do I gracefully handle all panic(s) and still continue to serve my client applications?

Comment: An unrecovered panic terminates the application.  Something else is going on if your application freezes.   [Effective Go describes how to recover](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#recover) from panics.

Comment: "a mechanism by which any unhandled panic [...] does not bring down my application". Such a mechanism doesn't exist by definition of "unhandled panic": Unhandled panics are meant to bring down the application.

Comment: Panic recovery must be explicitly implemented for each goroutine in your program.

Answer (score -1):

```
//You could use defer-recovery to handle all possible panic's 
func handelPanic(){
 if recoverPanic := recovery();recoverPanic != nil{
  fmt.Println("Panic is being recovered...")
   //Call function which you want to restart after panic is being recovered
 }
}    

func main() {
 defer handlePanic()
 //some code that needs to check err
 if err != nil{
     panic(err)
 }
}
```

Above following code will simply handle all panic's if recovery used in main function inside defer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).